# Extending the workspace in Libreoffice Impress

Tags: libreoffice-impress

I have a graphic that's three times the size of the visible page.  I want to animate it through the visible part of the slide, but the workspace is only as wide of the graphic.  Is there a way to increase the width of the workspace around the visible slide?